# move div on a page in the middle of a list of ul's but ul's do not id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div at the top of the page.

```
<div id="move">
    stuff
</div>
```

I want to move it down the page (not animate, but just have it be in another place in the DOM), right after the first of many ul's

```
<div class="maincolumn">
    <ul class="grid"></ul>
    <ul class="grid"></ul>
    <ul class="grid"></ul>
    <ul class="grid"></ul>
</div>
```

How can move that div from the top of the page to right after the first ul with no unique id's (no id's at all)? And note that there may be other ul's before this div.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have any working fiddle?

Comment: add that part of html after the first ul?

Comment: You write code, you write JavaScript code...

Comment: Something like `$('.maincolumn').children().eq(0).append(whatyouwanttoappen)` should perhaps work ?

Comment: it's not a valid question.

Comment: *move it down the page* is pretty unclear, How about simply copy pasting it there in `html`..? do you want to change it's position it `DOM`, or do you just want to visually change it's position..? can you explain what exactly you're doing and want to do..?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how else to explain it. I'm not able to just change the html, it's just time prohibitive because of the framework. So I'd rather do this with javascript/jquery. And I simply want the div to show up after the first ul inside div class main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `insertAfter()`

Try this

```
$('#move').insertAfter($('.maincolumn ul:eq(0)'))
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rFEER/50/)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you concluded that the OP wants to insert the node somewhere else in dom..? because *How can move that* is pretty vague… transitions, animations etc exists.

Comment: @TilwinJoy OP wants `I simply want the div to show up after the first ul inside div class main.`

Comment: That's great! One question though: what if it's not the first ul on the page? It's just the first ul in that div.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the *first* `ul`, then it's `ul:first`, so:

```
$("#move").insertAfter("ul:first");
```

That's using [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/), passing in the selector.

Comment: With all due respect, how did you concluded that the OP wants to insert the node somewhere else in dom..? because *How can move that* is pretty vague… transitions, animations etc exists.